# Ability to put browser toolbars back on a new window without toolbars

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, menu, add-on, toolbars

A few of our users are using a web application that removes the toolbars from the browser.  For tools they use, they need their toolbars.  Is there an IE add-on or can I write a javascript that we can add to the pages to give them a shortcut key, or some means to put the toolbars back?  What I've found so far is the page needs to be re-opened without the toolbars being removed, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just put them back, like after the page is loaded set the properties back to true.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I believe the short answer is no, this is not possible. Once the window options have been set, a window has to be reinitialized to change.

Comment: That's correct; if you open a window without toolbars, they're gone. There once was a bug where going into Fullscreen mode (via F11) then leaving brought the toolbars back, but I think that's gone.

Comment: Is there a way that I can create an add-on for internet explorer that will create a key combination and whenever the user hits that key it will execute window.open(location.href) which will give them their toolbars back by opening the current page in a new window?